# ASP.NET convert C to F. C# VS 2010... calculating error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to convert celsius to fahrenheit with C# ASP.net web forms in visual studio 2010.

I'm using a function to perform the conversion, including this code line:

`return (celsius * (9 / 5)) + 32;`

It doesn't calculate right! If I put in celsius = 16, I'm getting 48.

I've tried doing the same in PHP, - I'm getting 60, which is what I'm suppose to get.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing `9 / 5` being evaluated in *integer* arithmetic, giving the value of 1. So basically your expression is *just* adding 16.

You want something like:

```
// Force the 9.0 / 5.0 to be evaluated as a double
return (celsius * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32;
```

*Or* you could stay within integer arithmetic just by changing the evaluation grouping:

```
return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
```

If your input and expected output are integers, I'd go with the latter. Obviously there's now a greater risk of overflow... but only with *very* high temperatures :)

Note that this will always round *down* - if you want the mathemtically closest value, you'd probably want to *still* perform the arithmetic using floating point, then apply rounding, e.g.

```
return (int) (Math.Round((celsius * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32));
```

Note that this will use banker's rounding (round to even) for mid-points between two integers.

Comment: For the second solution you will get an answer much closer than OPs previous one - but it will still lose any fractional component if five times your Celsius temperature isn't evenly divisible by nine. If you want an integer return type, using floating point arithmetic followed by a round operation seems preferable and slightly more precise than a simple truncation. +1 for going into more detail than my answer though.

Comment: @thecoffman: Possibly. Depends on what the OP wants, I guess. Will edit to add a note.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this result because of **Integer Division.** 9 and 5 are integers - not floats/doubles/decimals or some other type capable of storing fractional parts of numbers. `9/5` results in `1` with the fractional component left off - and that's where your 48 is coming from. Try `9.0/5.0` and you should see a different result.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `celsius` is an `int` and 9 / 5 is being preformed as integer math.

Instead try:

```
return ((double)celsius * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your datatypes - make 9, 5 and 32 doubles; they're automatically assumed by C# to be ints.